# Making a datagrid with caption using TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, datagridview, panel, tablelayoutpanel

I want to make simple table with caption above it, but with tablelayoutPanel.
I make something  like this:

[image]

Now I want to make second row height to be just enough to display rows of datagridview. I have this function for that:

```
 public int GetCalculatedDataGridHeight(DataGridView dt)
    {
        int x = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<dt.RowCount;i++)
        {
            x += dataGridView1.Rows[i].Height;
        }
        x += dt.ColumnHeadersHeight;

        return x;

    }
```

This is rows collection of table layout panel:

[image]

And this is code
in form load:

```
 int x = GetCalculatedDataGridHeight(dataGridView1);

        ResourceSpecTableLayout.RowStyles[0].Height = ResTypeLb.Height;
        ResourceSpecTableLayout.RowStyles[1].Height = x;

        ResourceSpecTableLayout.Height = x + ResTypeLb.Height;
```

**I GET SOMETHING LIKE THIS:**

[image]

As you can see, the last row is cut, I don't know why, if I use this function on normal datagrid, it is displaying as it should be?

Comment: If you are just trying to add a label to a DGV, why not try a panel?

Comment: Did you include the dgv's border?

Comment: @Plutonix i tried with panel , and its displaying nicely , but why it isnt with TableLayoutPanel?